# How does the charts.js work with C3.js?

Tags: python, c3.js

I am really confused and would love some assistance

I have a dynamic json string i've created with pandas and the output is as follows.  I've also downloaded the c3 zip file in my flask directory

output of my function (from python/fask)

```
{"columns":["ECARS","MLD","ED","AQPSD","MSCD","ASD","ISD","TTD","OIS","RD","EO","CO"],"index":["Total_Employees","Completed","Remaining"],"data":[[243,180,172,163,161,149,138,102,93,79,70,37],[158,101,70,70,79,77,54,45,41,38,24,8],[85,79,102,93,82,72,84,57,52,41,46,29]]}
```

Is it possible it so that this is in a c3.js wrapper? i can configure the html files and css as well too, just trying to understand this concept and find out where everything needs to go

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"Is it possible it so that this is in a c3.js wrapper?"*?

Comment: i want to use python with c3.js but its needs to be in a specific json format